# How to send parameter value in async function

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I need to call a async function by sending some parameter. without parameter it is Ok, But I need to send parameter by its signature.

Here is my code :

// **This is my current code which is running without parameter.**

```
    private int Counting()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }

        return 0;
    }



    private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task<int> task = new Task<int>(Counting);
        task.Start();

        MessageBox.Show("Job started ..");

        int countValue = await task;

        MessageBox.Show("Job Done");

    }
```

// **But I need to do this as like :**

```
    private int Counting(int maxCount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }

        return 0;
    }



    private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task<int> task = new Task<int>(Counting(2000));
        task.Start();

        MessageBox.Show("Job started ..");

        int countValue = await task;

        MessageBox.Show("Job Done");

    }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use lambda syntax

```
Task<int> task = new Task<int>(() => Counting(2000));
```

[Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)